# PAM module: the counter in /var/faillog is never updated

Tags: login, pam

I am trying to find out the number of the failed logins attempts (since last successful login) for any given user.

The faillog -a reads the file /var/log/logfail, however the counter remains always 0 even though I enter a wrong password several times. I changed the permission of /var/log/failogto to a+rwx for testing.

Why does that happen and how can I capture this counter reliably? Any way to do it via pam_tally?

I want to shutdown the system with 3 unsuccessful login attempts, using PAM module pam_exec by running a script.